# How to indicate an element is loading without animation?

Tags: usability, web-app, animation, loading

I'm working on a product detail page that contains a 'Table of Contents'. Due to some not so great API work, I'm in a weird situation.

It takes between 10-20 seconds for the app to check if there is a Table of Contents. I want to indicate to the user that it is loading, but I'd rather not draw attention to this failure to load with an animation.

Is there anything better to show that this is actively loading than simple 'Loading...' static text? Does it seems worth it to add a loading animation, but risk having the user look at it early?

Edit: I forgot to mention this is a secondary element on the page. Hope this image helps a bit: 
[image]

Comment: 10-20 seconds is a very long time for a user to wait on the Web, particularly for something like a product page. Is it worth waiting for?

Comment: @MattObee Agreed it is painfully long. Unfortunately, Table of Contents is important when comparing two products. I was thinking we could hide it until it loaded, but I would be afraid the user would be confused why some had Table of Contents and others didn't because of load time.

Comment: That's the thing. If you don't draw attention to the fact that something is loading, why would they stick around and wait? If you do draw attention to it, you need to explain what's loading and why they should bother waiting.

Comment: @MattObee That's a really great point. I failed to mention this is a secondary element on the page, listed after the product details. My hope was someone would read the other details and by the time they made it to Table of Contents, it would be loaded.

I'll add an image to clarify.

Comment: I'm afraid that if you have 1/4 of the page showing content that isn't there then anything you do will draw attention to the fact that your system is sometimes slow

Comment: @DaveAlger True, maybe I just need to embrace that fact and just show the user it's loading versus getting tricky with it

Comment: I'd focus on the API. You're putting [lipstick on a pig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipstick_on_a_pig). 10-20 seconds is unacceptable.

Comment: @BernhardHofmann Don't I know it. Ug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you are doing is probably the best thing you can do given the situation.  Just show it as soon as you can and hope it isn't one of the crappy slow pages.

You have to show *something* in [1 second or less](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/response-times-3-important-limits/) and I would say a light colored static text is sufficient.

`Loading table of contents...`

Comment: Yeah, seems to be the best solution. Thanks for the advice